# Esri Runtime SDK WPF sample code cannot display raster nor shape file

Tags: sdk, esri

I have the license now and tried to run the sample code, I run the add raster and shapefile one. However the buttons works, you can select files however, it won't display the raster image or the shapefile, I don't think it even loads the data. The legend cannot expand after selecting data. The data is good because the sample application can run and display them though I use the WPF SDK

Answer (score 0):

Actually the reason is simple. Notice there is a line which about initialization string _emptyMpkPath = @"..\Data\DynamicLayers\EmptyMPK_WGS84.mpk"; This is very important.